# Курсор в текстовом поле

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

Не получается сделать простую функцию. Конструкция такая: при нажатии на кнопку, в текстовое поле textarea вставляется текст и поле обретает фокус. Но курсор ввода текста остается в самом начале, нужно его передвинуть после текста.

Вызываемая функция: `<a onclick="Response('#Msg','5');">Добавить</a>`

```
function Response(el,id){
    var old = $(el).val();
    $(el).val(old + '@' + id +', ');
    $(el).focus();
}
```

Что необходимо добавить в функцию, чтобы получить желаемый результат? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Nick, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на мой взгляд надо **сначала** передать фокус текстовому полю, а потом вставлять текст.

Comment: да а если не сработает, попробуйте добавлять в конец текста символ а потом после вставки удалять его, но думаю, должно сработать с фокусом

Comment: Вы гений! =) Не додумался, с фокусом получилось. Спасибо!